# Are men and women equal in terms of piety in Islam?

Tags: men-women, equality

According to [Islamqa](https://islamqa.info/en/1105) men and women are not equal.

So are men and women equal or not?

What I mean is, are men inherently better then women in terms of piety, just for them being men?

If there's any problem in my question please inform me. Thanks!

Comment: Unclear, be specific. Rights of husband vs rights of wife   etc. But in a very vague sense yes no one is equal Because every person has almost different rights and duties depending on his/her being a father, mother, brother, son daughter etc.

Comment: @AadilAhmed I edited it Assalamualaikum

Comment: Your linked fatwa already answers your question as it shows the differences. When it comes to piety we have no real possibility to measure as only Allah knows it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me give the answer from another prospective. For me, this question is doubtful.
I mean how is it possible that men and women can be equal. They are not equal at all; not biologically and not according to my understanding of Islam.

Maryam Jameelah, an American Jewish convert to Islam argues that comparing a man with a woman is like comparing a rose with a Jasmine, for each of them have their own color, fragrance, beauty, shape, characteristics, and features. She adds that "[w]omen are not equal to men. But neither are men equal to women." See *Islam and Western Society: A Refutation of the Modern Way of Life*, p. 109.

Therefore, for me, Islam does not give equal status to men and women but it gives justified status to both men and women according to their needs.

If you ask specifically about piety then the rule of Islam is clear in the Holy Quran:

> O mankind, indeed We have created you from male and female and made you peoples and tribes that you may know one another. Indeed, the most noble of you in the sight of Allah is the most righteous of you. Indeed, Allah is Knowing and Acquainted.  Surat-ul-Hujraat (49) Verses (13)

There is no distinction of men or women.

Comment: Even if I'd agree with you the question is about piety and not about equality in general which is already covered in a similar manner in the fatwa linked by OP, so you rather should elaborate on that.